# Dreamfactory : How to use MySQL aggregate functions in queries

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

With version 2 of dreamfactory, i'm unable to use aggregate functions as before in the filter or fields param.

Suppose example how can i query the following using api

```
SELECT HOUR(col2), MAX(col1)-MIN(col1)
FROM table_name
WHERE col3=CURDATE()
GROUP BY col3
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
1)DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (CURDATE) at
  position 0    (C): The timezone could not be found in the database.
2)Invalid field requested: HOUR(col2)
```

Comment: What is your output..Please explain what you need..

Comment: @jeffcarey, sorry i mean https://www.dreamfactory.com/

Comment: What error output are you getting?

Comment: @Drew Sorry about this.  In any case, the question isn't clear and doesn't provide any error output, so I'm moving on now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , added the error output

Comment: Not sure about the first one, but the second error seems to imply that `col2` is not a column in the `table_name` table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i'm sure there is a column with name `col2` in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to note. The "SELECT" fields can not contain function calls, but starting with version 2.0.2, DreamFactory supports [virtual fields](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Features/Database/Schema#virtual_fields). Create vcol2 to be "HOUR(col2)" and vcol1 to be "MAX(col1)-MIN(col1)" then use them in your field parameter.

As for the filter error, there is a bug in the parsing that is fixed in the 2.0.3 build coming out next week (12/21), but all function calls must be surrounded by parens, i.e. "col3 = (CURDATE())".

Here is the correct API query:

```
GET http://server/api/v2/service/_table/table_name?filter=col3%20%3D%20(CURDATE())&group=col3&fields=vcol2,vcol1
```